# Unable to instantiate a class defined in a subdirectory

Tags: python, oop, class, syntax

My (simplified) project layout is as follows:

```
/__init__.py
/test.py
/lib/__init__.py
/lib/client.py
```

my `test.py` is simply:

```
import lib.client
A = client()
A.Test()
```

and my `lib\client.py` begins as follows:

```
import ui #(another class in the lib dir)

class client(object):
    """
    (Blah)
    """
    UI = None

    def __init__():
        UI = ui()

    def Test():
        print "Success"
```

When I attempt to run test.py, I can step into the code and see that the definitions in client are parsed, however, when I get to the line where I instantiate a client, I get the following exception:

```
NameError: name 'client' is not defined
```

if I change that line to be:

```
A = lib.client()
```

Then I get

```
'module' object is not callable
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should do `from lib.client import client`. What you imported was the module file and as the error suggests, it is not callable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `lib.client` object you have after `import lib.client` is the module, not the class. To instantiate the class you need to call the class in the module object:

`A = lib.client.client()`

or, as @rantanplan said, import the class from the module

```
from lib.client import client
A = client()
```

Comment: Sorry for posting my answer, but I was midway finishing it while you posted yours :) +1 from me too.

Comment: By the way, I left this out, because I'm not sure this is PEP standard (yet?), but generally in large multi-level projects, it's good practice to keep the imported names as explicit as possible. e.g. `import foo.bar.baz` rather than `from foo.bar import baz`, as it makes it much clearer exactly what code base gets called whereever it is called (and also works well with module reloading, as the pointers persist, but their target is updated, although in most cases it's better to restart the process where possible.)

Comment: True, but `from bar import foo` and `import foo.bar.baz as fbz` is so convenient that is hard to ignore!

Comment: With `from bar import foo`, if you `reload(bar)`, `foo` remains the old version. I'm not sure how `import foo.bar.baz as fbz` behaves with module reloading. This isn't usually an issue, unless you have long-running processes that prefer to reload code rather than suffer downtime (e.g. servers,) but if you're in the habit doing the former, and suddenly find yourself in a situation where you need to reload, there will be a lot of code to rewrite.

Comment: Don't forget to include the `@username` symbol otherwise StackOverflow won't notify the person of any new comments! About the reloading, I really don't know all the pitfalls. Last I've read about it was that it was a bad practice and your code shouldn't rely on it anyway. Maybe things have changed though.

Comment: @rantanplan Oh, I agree it's a bad practice _in general_, but there are cases where the benefits outweigh the risks. It does require paying more attention to how your pointers are defined in every piece of code that _should_ be affected by a reload. However, large, long-running applications with a lot of reusable memory space to deallocate can take very long to shut down and clean up. You can't always afford that downtime for minor updates. It's a fringe case, for sure.

Answer (score 3):

I just understood that you do the imports the `Java` way.

In python when you do :

```
import lib.client
```

You don't make available all the definitions in that module. You just
made available the actual module - the `client.py`

So either you keep the import scheme as you have now and do

```
import lib.client
A = lib.client.client()
```

or

```
from lib.client import client
A = client()
```

Also I suggest you name your python classes with capitalized camelcase
i.e.

```
class Client(object):
```

As it is the python convention.

Comment: +1 for the very helpful and comprehensive answer. I'm going to award to @NisanH for beating you to the answer (and having a greater need for rep) but wanted to thank you for the detailed explanation

Comment: @Basic He deserves it, as I mislead him in thinking that I wouldn't post an answer, since I made a comment.