# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable API

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to instantiate a class defined in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389687/unable-to-instantiate-a-class-defined-in-a-subdirectory)

I have:

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import WykopLinks 
import WykopAPI


API = WykopAPI.WykopAPI('apikey')
Links = WykopLinks.WykopLinks(API)
List =  Links.getPromoted(); 
for Znalezisko in List:
print Znalezisko.id 
print Znalezisko.title
```

I tried to change the `import` to `from WykopLinks import WykopLinks` or change name on other name but this did not help.

Also I'm trying `other-name-formodule.WykopLinks(API)`

Error:

```
Links = WykopLinks(API)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I checked other problems described here, but none of them helps.

Comment: Please take care with your formatting when posting code. You failed to indent the print statements. In fact since the first and second blocks of code don't match, it's not obvious that you posted your real code.

Comment: Is there a site where this API can be downloaded or has documentation? All Google results point right back to this question. Without such documentation or code, this question is essentially unanswerable and too localized.

Comment: Documentation is in Polish lang, but here is link [Link](http://www.wykop.pl/developers/docs/#info7_5)

Anyway, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
Links = WykopLinks(API)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

fails just as the error message describes: `WykopLinks` is a module and is not callable.

Presumably you should be calling some function or class defined in the `WykopLinks` module. But since I can't find any documentation for that module, and since you didn't give any information, I can't tell you what the code should look like.

Comment: I changed `WykopLinks(API)` to `WykopLinks.WykopRespLinks(API)`.
In WykopLinks exist `class WykopRespLinks` but no `class WykopLinks` so added `WykopRespLinks` and works! Thx for the tip.

Comment: Yes.I edited previous post. Thanks again.